# invalid use of incomplete type (nested class case)

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, incomplete-type

how can I implement such an idea in C++ without getting into "invalid use of incomplete type" trouble?

```
class A {
    /*(...) some fields and methods here. */
    class B {
        /*(...) some fields and methods here. */
        friend B A::fun();
    };
    B fun();
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
struct A {
    class B;
    B fun();
    class B {
        friend B A::fun();
    };
};
```

Comment: I am sorry, I oversimplified my case and there's a little bit more trouble in here. Please take a look at the updated version of my question, thank you in advance.